# Android Studio open project structure fail

Tags: android, android-studio, project-structure

I created new project in Android Studio in Ubuntu 12.04.

When the project opened, I can't config project structure. It says

> We will provide a UI to configure project settings later. Until then,
>   please manually edit your build.gradle file(s.)

What can I do? I imported a eclipse project. IS it OK?

I can config project structure in *Windows* when I create a new project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. Currently Android Studio follows (Google) Gradle Android project structure
so by default

```
<project root>
    <src>
        <main>
            <java>
            <res>
        <instrumentTest>
            <java>
            <res>
```

If your project structure is different you can fiddle with it adding

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']

            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']

            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

to match old project structure. For full documentation how to use gradle android plugin go

[New Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)

Comment: yes. There is no interaction between build.gradle and Android Studio project files so for building project update build.gradle file. If Android Studio doesn't show sources use Project Settings GUI to set them.